# zsh alias not being unaliased in zshrc

Tags: zsh, alias, macos

[leading dots elided because I don't want to type them]

An alias--gl--is set to git pull by a plugin in my zshrc. I want to set it to a git log command.

I'm on macOS and, as expected, /etc/zshrc is not aliasing anything to git pull. My zprofile is empty, and I have no zlogin. The **last** three lines of my zshrc are:

```
unalias gl
alias gl="git log --pretty=medium --decorate --date=short"
alias gpl="git pull"
```

After an `exec zsh` the unalias command errs with "no such hash table element: gl". An immediate `alias gl` returns gl='git pull'.

Running `zsh -ixc : | grep "alias gl"` returns nothing. `zsh -ixc : | grep "git pull"` returns nothing. However immediately running `alias gl` returns `gl='git pull'`.

I can unalias and realias gl to my desired command on the command line.

Comment: Your greps won't work because the thing you're trying to grep is in stderr.

Comment: Ahah! Thank you @muru -- I'll take a new look. Unfortunately that's not the problem. If I redirect to 2>&1 and grep for "bindkey" all of the appropriate results show up.

Comment: Those aliases could very well be set from within code where the `xtrace` option is disabled or stderr is redirected to /dev/null. Like in `zsh -xc '() { emulate -LR zsh; alias gl="git pull"; }'` or `zsh -xc '{ alias gl="git pull"; } 2> /dev/null'`

Comment: Maybe a plugin sets up a hook function that changes aliases when the current directory is a git worktree. Does it make a difference if the current directory is a git worktree when you restart zsh? Try `typeset -f | grep alias` to see if some functions change aliases.

Comment: There are, indeed, 30 more lines inside of a git worktree. Some of which mention aliases. I'll need to dig down and see exactly what's going on. Thanks so much!

Comment: `oh-my-zsh` has `alias gl='git pull'` in its git plugin, so you could be picking it up from there. `omz` also adds some precmd hooks, which might explain the weird behavior you're seeing with `unalias`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use OMZ. I use zinit. @Gilles answer above is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`^R` was bound to `history-incremental-search-backward` by the plugin [zsh-vim-mode](https://github.com/softmoth/zsh-vim-mode). Commenting it out allowed my binding of `^R` to `fzf-history-widget` to work.

The original mapping was achieved by `vim-mode-bindkey viins vicmd -- history-incremental-search-backward '^R'`.